# Suggest Java Swing Component libraries

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, components

I’m currently looking for a Java Swing all-in-one professional component pack to create good-looking UIs, charts, reports and so on. Surprisingly, after a couple of hours of googling all I was able to find is [JIDE](http://www.jidesoft.com/). Even though it looks sexy, I need more alternatives to choose from. Are there any recommendations? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately there are very few alternatives. Writing GUI with Java is just not in. JIDE is the only large component library I'm aware of.

Comment: I noticed it :) I wish our company could switch to .NET -- UIs in Java look ugly + C# is way more powerful. Alas, this is not possible and Java is the only choice :o

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at SwingX:

- http://www.swinglabs.org/
- https://swingx.dev.java.net/

For charts, look at [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/). For reports, look at [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) or [Eclipse BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/).

Answer (score 4):

[SwingZx](http://sriver111.blogspot.sg/2012/09/swingzx-java-swing-control-library-for.html)

Simple swing component lib with cool buttons.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: This library is not available for download anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this lib: [swing-components](https://github.com/lightblueseas/swing-components) MIT license